# Access ECK elasticsearch running on Kubernetes using Minikube from browser

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, minikube

I have eck elasticsearch service running on Kubernetes using Minikube(Podman) on Mac. I am able to access elasticsearch instance from browser using kubectl command: `kubectl port-forward service/elasticsearch-sample-es-http 3002:9200` but I want to access the elasticsearch from browser using NodePort or Ingress service. Below is my elasticsearch yaml file code::

````
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-sample
spec:
  version: 7.15.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
    podTemplate:
      metadata: 
        labels:
          app: elastic-search
      spec:
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
          runAsGroup: 1000
          fsGroup: 1000
    count: 2
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: NodePort
        ports: 
          - name: https
            port: 9200
            targetPort: 9200
            protocol: TCP
            nodePort: 31920```


I tried with both NodePort and Ingress but not able to access the elasticsearch instance.
````

Comment: Hi \`Shubham Gupta\` are you getting any error when you are using nodeport configuration and can you provide the documentation which you are following for configuring your cluster. Also check whether any mac security policies are blocking creation of nodeport.<br>

Comment: You need to create the Ingress yourself. Please show how you've tried that